# Empty xml object when using SimpleXML - Node no longer exists

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

The xml is as follows:

```
<root>
   <organizations>
        <organization>
          <info>
            <orgID>1234</orgID>
            <orgName>XYZ Company</orgName>
            <address>
                <address1>1 Main Street</address1>
                <city>Somewhere</city>
                <state>MI</state>
                <zip>12334</zip>
            </address>
          </info>
         </organization> 
      </organizations>
</root>
```

The code is as follows:

```
$ind = strpos($xmlResponse, "<");
$xml = simplexml_load_string(substr($xmlResponse, $ind));
//echo $xml;
$orgList = $xml->organizations->children();

foreach($orgList as $orgList)
{
    echo $orgList->orgName;
}
```

And I get the following error:

`Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in...`

The offending line is 
    `foreach($orgList as $orgList)`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried accessing the xml through 50 different ways and either get that error or an empty xml object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath

Put the XML in x.xml file
then create php file:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('x.xml');
    $orgList = $xml->xpath("/root/organizations/organization/info");
    print $orgList[0]->orgName; 
?>
```

Comment: I get the following two errors when attempting the above:  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in and Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: Why does it seem that I don't have an xml object? I can echo out the initial $xml and I get valid output immediate after loading the string via simplexml_load_string

Comment: what version of php do you have? to check (<?php echo phpversion(); ?> ).. get php 5 to run xpath!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're overwriting the xml object when you loop with $orgList as $orgList. Try this instead:

```
foreach($orgList as $org)
   echo $org->orgName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$org = $xml->organizations->children();

foreach($org as $k => $v)
{
    echo $v->info->orgName;
}
```

Comment: The only changes that I have really made include; changing the naming convention for the key/value pair to be used in the loop, and adding a missing object access level 'info'.